# About Geodesic polar coordinate

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

What is different from geodesic polar coordinates and other polar coordinates?

Geodesic polar coordinates has a form of
$$ds^2=dr^2+f(r,\theta)^2\,\,d\theta^2$$

In $S^2$, $f(r,\theta)=\sin(r)$ which reduces to 
\begin{align}
ds^2=dr^2+\sin(r)^2 d\theta^2
\end{align}
Here $r$ and $\theta$ are angle coordinates,

In spherical coordinates we know, orthonormal frame 
\begin{align}
ds^2=dr^2 +r^2 d\theta^2 +r^2\sin(\theta)^2 d\phi^2
\end{align}
Here $r$ is radial and $\theta$, $\phi$ are polar, azimuthal angle. $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, $\pi \in [0,2\pi]$

We can simply set sphere to be constant radius $i.e$ $r=1$, so that this metric reduces to the form 
\begin{align}
ds^2=d\theta^2+\sin(\theta)^2 d\phi^2
\end{align}
Actually it is same with geodesic polar coordinates in $S^2$.

---

Here i am confused with terminology geodesic polar coordinates?

I want to know the exact definition of geodesic polar coordinates.

I know geodesic normal coordinate is defined by, for its coordinate, $p$,  given metric's first order derivative is vanishes. $i.e$ $\partial g |_p=0$